# Angular Material versions differ on the same installation after upgrade

Tags: angular, angular-material

To update the **Angular Material version**, I ran:

```
npm update @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

After doing so, the **package.json** file looks like:

```
[... snip ...]
 "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "8.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
[... snip ...]
```

which shows

```
@angular/material": "8.0.1", 
@angular/cdk": "8.0.1",`
```

C:\WorkEnvironment\Developments>ng --version

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.23
Node: 12.14.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.23
@angular-devkit/core               7.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.23
@angular/cdk                       8.0.1
@angular/cli                       8.3.23
@angular/flex-layout               8.0.0-beta.26
@angular/material                  8.0.1
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.23
@schematics/angular                8.3.23
@schematics/update                 0.803.23
rxjs                               6.5.2
typescript                         3.4.5
webpack                            4.39.2
```

- BUT -

when I do (from within Visual Studio Code)

```
PS C:\WorkEnvironment\Development> npm -v
6.13.4
```

Why is there a difference? Can it be fixed?

TIA

Comment: how's npm version related to material?

Comment: New to Angular & Material. Iinfo was not known at the time of the post. Thanks.

Comment: No pb, glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm -v
```

just shows the version of the npm tool.

To check the installed packages of the current project (directory), try:

```
npm list
```

The recent versions of Visual Studio Code also show the installed package versions when you open the package.json file.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) I saw "npm" is used with many Angular commands, is it OK for it to exist at this version (6.13.4) when everything else is sitting at 8.0 or higher?

Comment: The version of your npm and the version of the npm packages you install are two different things. There is no relation between those versions. So you are good to go!